# How much data needed to test my hypothesis

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, data-analysis

Suppose we have a data stream which outputs integer values from $0$ to $2^{32}-1$. We know that either (A) all values occur equally often or (B) exactly half of the values occur $2^{10}$ times more often than the other half (but it is unknown which values are more likely).

I'd like to know how I can approach whether (A) or (B) is true. Also, I've been asked to state how many values I would need to observe to be confident of my result with a probability of $0.999$. Moreover, assume we can only observe up to $2^{18}$ values.

My rough attempt at a solution. We gather a certain amount of data, for example $2^{10} = 1024$ integers. We then record how many of these fall in the first half of possible values, that is $0$ to $2^{31}-1$. If (A) is true, all values are equally likely so one would expect to see around $512$ fall in this half. If (B) is true, the expected value could be anything so we would almost definitely get a very different amount.

This method makes sense to me but I don't know how many values I would need to observe to be confident enough to say the result is true with probability $0.999$.  I've been told it is something to do with using the 3-sigma rule for a normal distribution but I'm not sure how I should apply this here.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: what do you expect to get if you sample N values and add them together?

Comment: That above hint can be used if you want to employ normal distribution properties (do you see how?) . I think it's more straightforward to directly calculate the probability of certain events happening (or not)

Comment: Regarding the hint, I imagine I would use the central limit theorem so I could then work with a normal distribution. But I'm still unclear how to proceed with that. Could you maybe suggest a "certain event" I should try calculating the probability of to start me off.

Comment: Correct, you can use the central limit theorem. No need to think of "certain events" this way (my comment about that was for another method). Just find how your normal distributions will look like if you add 50 samples, depending on which of the three cases is true (numbers from whole interval, bottom half, top half). How much are they "separated". What if you add 100 samples?

Comment: As more and more samples are added I would expect to see the mean of the normal distributions converge to the central value of the interval (if case (A) is true). I still don't know how to make this rigorous though to get the required result of being 99.9% certain

Comment: The mean will be the middle point (times the number of samples) even if you take just one sample. What improves with more samples is the approximation to the normal distribution. Let's assume that for $n\ge 20$ samples the approximation is close enough. How do the normal distributions for the 3 cases discussed above look like? Do you see how the distributions of these 3 cases become more and more separated as we take more samples?

Comment: I'm not sure what the 3 cases refers to. There are only 2 cases. All values are equally likely or an unspecified half is more likely than the other half. Thus when we take many samples we will either see a normal distribution with mean = central point or mean = some other point we have no way of knowing. Then you can easily tell which case is true, but again I don't know how to make this rigorous. For instance, what if case (B) was true but by chance the mean happened to be also close to the central point?

Comment: Case 1: samples taken from the whole interval uniformly. Case 2 samples taken from the bottom half uniformly (and with very small probability from the rest of the interval). Case 3: samples taken from the top half. Cases 2 and 3 are symmetrical so you can  consider only one of them.

Comment: Right, but how do we know to look at the bottom or top half of the interval? We don't know it's those values that are more common than the others. It could be any union of sub intervals that comes to half in total, such as the first 20% and the last 30%.

Comment: Wait a minute, so far I was assuming that we are talking about the bottom and top halves. If **any** partition is possible then this is a different problem. My first reaction to this is that you probably cannot tell which space you are sampling from with just $2^{18}$ values.

Comment: I thought about it more and I believe there is a way to tell apart cases A and B (with any partition into halves) with less than $2^{18}$ samples. I have not solved the problem fully, but a hint I can give you is to think about the birthday paradox.

Comment: Ok, I have an idea based on your hint. We calculate the probability of getting a repeat value appear in $N$ samples given case A, and then the same assuming case B. This will be higher in case B since half the values are more common. We then take N large enough to make $P(Repeat | B) > 0.999$.

Comment: Yes, this is the general idea. We look at how many repeats we get with N samples. The specific test you propose will not work very well, because the probability of at least one repeat will be high in both cases (higher for case B of course). So witnessing one repeat will not reveal much information. The key is finding the probability of multiple repeats.